Custom QuickLook plugin for SMB mount point
I am new to Mac OS world, so please ignore my naivety.
I am having trouble trying to understand QuickLook thumbnail/preview behavior on SMB mounted paths. From the network trace, it seems to generate the thumbnails, the entire image/pdf file is being read(I checked Wireshark). For MP4 files, a lot of data is being read(not sure exactly how much).
But this behavior is troubling as it delays content listing and generates unnecessary traffic. I have a dedicated thumbnail server as well and I was hoping to implement my own QL generator that would be used for the files on SMB mount path. The generator can fetch the thumbnails from this server.
I am not sure if this is possible for well-known file types. Is this even doable ? Can I define my own UTI for all the files residing on SMB share and then use my custom generator for this ?
I saw that DropBox has its own QL generator as well. And from the info.plist it seems to trying hooking into all the well-known file types as well. But qlmanage -m seems to be ignoring it and using the system provided generator only
I found some threads around this here and here, but could not figure out if this is feasible

The only right way to do this is to make a FileProvider extension that will expose your SMB mount, instead of mounting the server directly. Then you will have control over thumbnails inside your file provider.

You mean, FileProvider manages the SMB traffic, right ? Implement a custom SMB client that FileProvider uses to interact with the SMB server. Mac will interact with FileProvider

Yes. This way you have control over the « fetch thumbnail from the network » API. This is not exposed anywhere for regular SMB connections.
